# Parsing parameters in Python Cmd module

Tags: python, cmd

I am writing a command line tool in Python using the Cmd module.

I want to be able to issue commands such as:

```
resize -file all -height 100 -width 200 -type jpeg
```

or

```
resize -file 'a file.jpg' -type png -height 50 -width 50
```

[edit] To be clear the above command is to be enter into my command line application NOT from the terminal. The line above would call the do_resize(self, line) method of my Cmd module and pass in the parameters as a string. For this reason OptParse and argparse don't do what I need as they appear to only get paramters from sys.argv.

Some parameters are required, some are optional. Some become required when others are used.

**What is the best way to parse the parameter string?** I have read there are tools in Python that make this easy but I'm not sure what I'm look for.

Comment: What about `getopt` ? http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html

Comment: Or alternative `argparse`: http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are looking for [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) ([argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) for python 2.7+)

**edit:** In fact according to [this](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#parsing-arguments) section of docs, you can call function `parse_args` passing a list of arguments, which defults (but not limits to) `sys.argv[1:]`

So, if you have for example `args_str = '-file all -height 100 -width 200 -type jpeg'` you can call `parser.parse_args(args_str.split())` and it will parse correctly the options.

Comment: On second thoughts I don't think this is what I am looking for. As far as I can see these only get parameters from sys.argv whereas I am trying to get them from a string that has been input into my Cmd module at runtime. See my edit above.

Comment: you can get parameters from whatever array of arguments (you can split a string to get an array of args), I updated my answer

Comment: I owe you a huge thanks! I've been working since yesterday and could not figure out a way to parse argument through the argpars instance.

Answer (score 3):

Best option is the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

I love [getopt](http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html) because it is simple.

Comment: I did consider this but according to the documentation it doesn't support optional arguments.

Answer (score 1):

How about the [shlex](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html) module. I think it is exactly for this purpose.